# Issue with searching in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have a textbox and a datagridew in my winform.The dgvw is connected to a sql database with code.I have added a code to search the datagridview in the textbox's textchange event.The problem is, suppose i type something in the textbox, the dgvw shows me the results instantly,but after i'm done with searching , i clear the textbox with backspace and when i click on any button on the form the dgvw becomes empty! THERE ARE NO ROWS OR COLUMNS.But whn i click on the textbox and type something they again appear...What should i do ?

```
Private Sub OffPo_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from userandadmins", con)
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim table As New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(table)
            userdatagrid.DataSource = table
            Dim imm As New DataGridViewImageColumn
            imm = userdatagrid.Columns(0)
            imm.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
            userdatagrid.Columns(0).Width = 35
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
Private Sub filterdata(valuetosearch As String)
        Dim srq As String = "Select * from userandadmins where CONCAT(Title,FirstName,LastName,Phone,Mobile,Email,AccountType,Username,Password) like '%" & valuetosearch & "%' "
        Dim mycmd As New SqlCommand(srq, con)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(mycmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(table)
        userdatagrid.DataSource = table
    End Sub


Private Sub textbox1_textchanged
        filterdata(textbox1.text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming `valueToSearch` is a string which the user typed, then your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using .NET. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: You have written your search code in the text box change event. If you clear the text box with backspace means there are no search criteria. So the DataGridView getting empty (no row no column)

Comment: The reason for the actual error I would guess is that your LIKE statement never matches an empty string. You probably need some logic such that when the search value is empty / null, don't include the WHERE clause in the query

Comment: can anyone please give me the correct/fixed code??Pleaseee

Comment: Consider a search button instead of TextChanged event. Your code is working, you have told it to search when text changes and clearing the textbox is a change.

Comment: but wait! The dgv doesn't empty itself when the textbox is empty, but when the textbox is empty and i click on a button then the dgvw goes empty...so ? any solution ? I really don't want to add a search button